# Replacing XML serialization of class member

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

In my class (Camera), that I need to serialize, I have one member which doesn't have much serialization means and I can't modify its class. But there are only 2-3 parameters out of whole class that I can serialize and then de-serialize based on that.

```
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Camera));
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, cc);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

How and where can I put custom serialization code, to take those 2-3 parameters from object and give to serializer, then during de-serialization create again that object using those 2-3 parameters.

Update. The example code:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Camera
{
    public string name;
    public int index;
    public double distance;
    public List<string> CameraList { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public GMarkerGoogle marker;

    public Camera()
    {
    }

}
```

`marker` is the member that doesn't have serialization means. But there with `marker.position`, `marker.rotation` I can re-create that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to Xml serialize your GMarker then make sure that you do serialize the properties needed to reconstruct it (kind of what you already suggested). That way you can make a property with backing field to lazy recreate the GMarker.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Camera
{
    public string name;
    public int index;
    public double distance;
    public List<string> CameraList { get; set; }

    private GMarkerGoogle _marker;
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public GMarkerGoogle Marker
    {
        set
        {
            _marker = value;
            MarkerPosition = _marker.position;
            MarkerRotation = _marker.rotation;
        }
        get
        {
            if (_marker == null)
            {
                _marker = new GMarkerGoogle(MarkerPosition, MarkerRotation);
            }

            return _marker;
        }
    }

    public double MarkerPosition { get; set; }
    public double MarkerRotation { get; set; }

    public Camera()
    {
    }
}
```

Does this help? I made up a thing or two because I don't know the API for the marker, but I hope you can draw the picture from this point onwards.

Comment: @Pablo not that i know off. Ill upvote your question, maybe it draws some attention :)

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the `IXmlSerializable` interface in your `Camera` class.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) for more info.

Alternatively you could use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to flag the properties you do not want to serialize to XML.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx) for more info :).

PS: If you post some code I can show you an example but you probably don't need me. Let me know if you do though.

Comment: But with this I have to handle all members of my class manually? It's not clear from MSDN.

Comment: @Pablo Well yeah that's the idea. If you don't want to specify which properties to serialize; there is an alternative way, you can also flag properties to ignore them during xml serialization. updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I understand I can ignore, but after ignoring I have to replace that object with couple other XML elements in order to re-create it. `IXmlSerializable` will take me down to XML implementation details, such as writing manually elements. I brought an example code. Would appreciate a small example modification for the clue.

Comment: Well, originally I thought there is a way to override something in my class, so when serializer will start dealing with `marker` I could give him some custom members...

Comment: @Pablo I added an additional answer to cover the code bit. Does that work for you? Or did it not cover your question?

Comment: @bas I'm checking now, will let you know soon. This looks the only obstacle is I have to carry those `MarkerPosition` all the way although they are only for serialization. But perhaps there is no better solution to this.